# Remaining Tooltips on scroll with Firefox + Windows

Tags: windows, html, forms, firefox, tooltip

I have a form with HTML5 validation. It's a simple input field with a required parameter.

```
<input type="text" id="form_at_code" name="form[at][code]" required="required" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="11" class="numbersOnly" placeholder="Code d'activation">
```

If I validate the form with an empty field, the HTML5 validation fires and a tooltip is displayed.

So far so good.

But if I scroll, the tooltip remains on screen.

[image: Remaining tooltips]

When I click, the tooltip vanishes.

Any idea how to prevent this behavior ?

More info :

- Firefox (latest version - just downloaded it, something like 55.*)
- Windows (tested on 7 and 10) (I can't reproduce it on Mac)
- jQuery 2.2.3

Comment: 1) Maybe explicitly set focus to another element.

Comment: 2) Your tooltip container might be too large and might be getting activated when it shouldn't be.